# Display the latest post from some selected authors

Tags: posts, loop, query

I'm building a slider that will display the latest post of a few selected authors. So far, I've written this:

`<?php
    $args  = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'author'         => $user->ID
    );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="author-box-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>`

and I don't get anything as a result. Can you tell me what's wrong with this? Also, is there a better way to generate the latest post by author?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: That should work, granted that $user->ID contains a user id.

Comment: My guess would be that `$user` is undefined. How do you get `$user`. Do a `var_dump($user)` and make sure that you have a value

Comment: The $user-ID is working as intended because I generate the images and the links to their profiles; but I still can't get their latest post to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts_by_author_sql

```
<?php
$where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post', true, $user->ID);

// get post query
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts $where";
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $query, 'Get all posts' ) );
?>
```

Did not try it but something simular in your case should help.